# Comparison lemma for (certain) Grothendieck quasitoposes

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

In the context of Grothendieck toposes, the Comparison Lemma says that if $(\mathbb{C}, \mathcal{J})$ is a small site and $\mathbb{B} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a full subcategory  with induced Grothendieck topology $\mathcal{K}$ such that every object of $\mathbb{C}$ has a covering by objects of $\mathbb{B}$, then we have an equivalence of categories $\mathsf{Sh}(\mathbb{C}, \mathcal{J}) \simeq \mathsf{Sh}(\mathbb{B}, \mathcal{K})$.

Does a similar result hold (more generally) for categories of *separated* presheaves, i.e. Grothendieck quasitoposes of the form $\mathsf{Sep}(\mathbb{C}, \mathcal{J})$, rather than categories of sheaves?

Comment: We have something similar and even stronger: The category of presheaves over $\Bbb A$ is isomorphic to the category of presheaves over $\Bbb B$ if and only if the *idempotent completions* of $\Bbb A$ and $\Bbb B$ are equivalent.

Comment: @Berci Isomorphic, really? It’s also not obvious how that’s stronger than the claim in the question.

Comment: Of course, equivalent.

Comment: @Berci I was actually asking about the categories $\mathsf{Sep}(\mathbb{C}, \mathcal{J})$ of *separated* presheaves over a site, not the entire presheaf categories. Should I make that clearer in my question? Or does your answer relate/apply to categories of separated presheaves as well?

Comment: No, sorry, yes, I think you can make that clearer.